# ThreeJS - How to Add HDRi Equirectangle map (for lighting the scene) while keeping the background transparent(alpha)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add HDRi lighting using HDR EQUIRECTANGLE Texture to the scene. But I don't want to see that HDRi image, I want the scene to be a transparent one. I'm using HDRI Haven website to download images. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            scene.environment =  envMap;
            //scene.background = envMap;
```

Comment: Yea this stops rendering the env map, and also no problem with the object it perfectly receives the light, **but the canvas is still not transparent**, I've also tried adding  alpha:true for the webGL renderer. the canvas bg is black.

Comment: Oh! on your rendering constructor set "preserveDrawingBuffer:true;alpha:true;" and then also make sure that No elements including the canvas and any of its parent containers have a background style set. hth!

Comment: Yea its my parent containers bg style :D I Removed that and now it works like a charm! Thanks a million! <3 @manthrax

Comment: Great! I have gotten burned by that before :D Took me houurs to figure out!